# Get output of remote command locally

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

Let's assume I have a remote server with ssh access.
On the server, there is a command 'cmd_x' when I execute it, it will open an interactive command line where I can write commands (specific commands) and obtain an output.
Can I execute 'cmd_x' commands remotely and get results using one command line, as we do to get for example the remote 'ls' output locally:

```
ssh remote_host "ls > /tmp/file_on_remote_host.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-t` before the command like so:

```
ssh remote_host -t "ls > /tmp/file_on_remote_host.txt"
```

More info here https://www.mankier.com/1/ssh#-t

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly unclear about where you want the output saved - you say "locally", but do you mean (A) local to the remote system, or (B) on the client where you issue the `ssh` command?

In either scenario, you need the `-t` option to force open a pseudo-tty.  Then, to be able to see the presumed prompts to which you need to respond,  you'll need to use `tee` to both collect the output and see it back on the client.

For (A) (save on remote system):
`ssh -t remote_host 'cmd_x | tee /tmp/file_on_remote_host.txt'`

For (B) (save output on local client):
`ssh -t remote_host cmd_x | tee /tmp/file_on_local_host.txt`

Notice the only difference is the quotes around the command to issue the entire pipeline on the remote host, or not.